# Changing learning rate by external function, do I have to run many sessions?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Function, call it DetermineLearningRate that takes in the accuracy (and other metrics) at each iteration and gives the learning rate to a simple CNN.

Workflow

1. Simple CNN DetermineLearningRate() would take in the accuracy and
   return a learning rate
2. The TensorFlow Graph of the CNN would take in
   the learning rate and run 1 iteration and return the accuracy
3. This repeats until all iterations over.

If I have 10,000 iterations, does this mean I have to run and close 10,000 sessions? This is because I do not want the iterations to carry on without my function calling at each iteration, getting the accuracy then returning the learning rate.

This is the workflow I had in mind:

1. Global variable LR that the graph accesses
2. Run session 1 with the LR given by function
3. Get the accuracy
4. Close the session
5. Run session 2 with the LR given by the function after getting the
   accuracy
6. Get accuracy
7. Close the session
8. Repeat

Can someone advice? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No it is much simpler than that just create a placeholder for the learning rate `LR=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[])` and use the value from your function as a feed_dict argument to your training step.

**WALKTHROUGH:**

So suppose you have defined a graph that looks something like this and a function `DetermineLearningRate()` to calculate your learning rate:

```
x=tf.placeholder([None,dim_x],tf.float32)
target=tf.placeholder([None,dim_target],tf.float32)
LR=tf.placeholder([],tf.float32)
#a list of operations on x to get y_pred
y_pred=...
#Your loss
loss=your_loss_function(y_pred,target)
acc=accuracy(y_pred,target)
#I am now passing the placeholder LR as a learning rate
train_step = tf.train.YourFavoriteOptimizer(LR).minimize(loss)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in xrange(training_steps):
  acc_arg=sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x: batch_x, target: batch_target}) 
  lr_val=DetermineLearningRate(acc_arg)
  #lr is a scalar not a list
  sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x: batch_x, target: batch_target, LR: lr_val})
```

Notice that I never closed a session.
There are other more elegant ways of doing this but in my opinion this is the most straightforward.
Like you could define LR as a tensor obtained from the tensor acc through tensorflow operations like `LR=tf.div(1,acc)` or whatever and only use one call to `ses.run()`.
Or use a non-trainable Variable for LR and `tf.assign` the result of your function to it.

**EDIT:** To prevent an operation from runing in TF before another one finishes you can use `tf.control_dependencies()`.

Comment: However, the external function has to get the accuracy first (end of previous iteration) before giving the learning rate at the start of the next iteration. This only passes a list of values as the learning rate right? Do you've a sample of how this might work?

Comment: Did that help ?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. But the problem I mentioned is how:

The iteration should not move unless my external function gets the accuracy from the previous batch and return the learning rate for TF to use in the next batch.

My external function is a loop:
```
for i in 1000: 
    lr = determineLearningRate(accuracy)
    accuracy = someFunctionToGetAccuracyFromTF(lr)
```

Comment: I am not very clear with what you are asking but if you want to wait for another operation to finish before runing another one you are looking for tf.control_dependencies().